# open_basedir restriction on phpMyAdmin

Tags: apache-2.4, open-basedir

I'm trying to reinstall my server and have run into a new problem that I can't seem to figure out.

I'm running a LAMP setup and host a few sites for my friends, for that I have open_basedir set in their Apache conf files but that suddenly affect phpMyAdmin (Warning: Unknown: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php) is not within the allowed path)

It works fine if I remove the open_basedir from the virtual host.

What really confuses me is that this has never been an issue in any of my previous setups, has something changed or am I doing something wrong this time?

Apache2.4.18
php 7.0.4
phpMyAdmin 4.5.4.1

Comment: How was defined the open_basedir when there is the error ? You should have /usr/share/phpmyadmin in it to solve your problem.

Comment: That has never before been necessary on the specific virtual hosts. And it is set in /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf which is included in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that phpMyAdmin wasn't set up to php7
So all I had to do was change

```
<IfModule mod_php.c>
```

to

```
<IfModule mod_php7.c>
```

in /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf